# SAP Web Worldpay Correlation Issue in Loadrunner

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

Loadrunner could not capture integrationID for worldpay payment

I already checked in the code generation that the value of the regular expression is correct and it is place in the right request

Here is the code:

```
/*Correlation comment - Do not change!  Original value='1560785768009' Name ='c_integrationID' Type ='Manual'*/
    web_reg_save_param_regexp(
        "ParamName=c_integrationID",
        "RegExp=\\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ data-iframe-integration-id=\"(.*?)\"\\\n\\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ data-iframe-origin",
        SEARCH_FILTERS,
        "Scope=Body",
        "IgnoreRedirections=No",
        LAST);

    web_url("corporate",
        "URL=https://payments-test.worldpay.com/app/hpp-iframe/integration/wpg/corporate?OrderKey=DYSONUSDMOTO^{c_orderKey}&Ticket={c_ticket}&language=en&preferredPaymentMethod={preferredPaymentMethod}&iframeIntegrationId={c_integrationID}&iframeHelperURL=https%3A%2F%2Fuk-cr-ap1vpt1.dysonsap.sap%3A1443%2Fsap%2Fbc%2Fbsp%2Fsap%2Fzworldpay%2Fhelper.htm",
        "Resource=0",
        "RecContentType=text/html",
        "Referer=https://uk-cr-sapvpt1.dysonsap.sap/sap(bD1lbiZjPTIwMA==)/bc/bsp/sap/zworldpay/worldpay.htm?wp_url=https%3a%2f%2fpayments-test.worldpay.com%2fapp%2fhpp%2fintegration%2fwpg%2fcorporate%3fOrderKey%3dDYSONUSDMOTO%255E{c_orderKey}%26amp%3bTicket%3d{c_ticket}%26language%3den%26preferredPaymentMethod%3d{preferredPaymentMethod}",
        "Snapshot=t649.inf",
        "Mode=HTTP",
        LAST);
```

I expect that it will be captured using the code above but it has an error
Here is the error log:

```
OrderPaymentUS.c(132): Error -26631: HTTP Status-Code=400 (Bad Request) for "https://payments-test.worldpay.com/app/hpp-iframe/integration/wpg/corporate?OrderKey=DYSONUSDMOTO^A002351833&Ticket=00156311234916702AMjvRLdQFlAbLxT6-rZh0g&language=en&preferredPaymentMethod=ECMC-SSL&iframeIntegrationId={c_integrationID}&iframeHelperURL=https%3A%2F%2Fuk-cr-ap1vpt1.dysonsap.sap%3A1443%2Fsap%2Fbc%2Fbsp%2Fsap%2Fzworldpay%2Fhelper.htm"     [MsgId: MERR-26631]
OrderPaymentUS.c(132): Error -35049: No match found for the requested parameter "c_integrationID". Check whether the requested regular expression exists in the response data   [MsgId: MERR-35049]
```

Comment: Could you please send the question with the script to the feedback email? In Vugen go to Help->Send us your feedback.

Comment: Issue has been resolved. We just correlated the card_guid.

Comment: Great! If you need more assistance with the product feel free to ask.